# Tabbar cannot clickable after iPhone 5 optimize

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar, iphone-5

I am optimizing my screen from iphone 4 to iphone 5. However, Once I have optimized, my tabbar stopped working. As it can be seen in the first image, once I clicked on world average, it took me, tabbarcontroller and now user cannot able to click on tabbar segments.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue and this worked for me:

Go to the MainWindow.xib, select the Window object and check the "Full Screen at Launch".